# NLTK sent_tokenize

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm using NLTK's sent_tokenize to split sentences.

The module doesn't split sentences with abbreviations such as U.S., U.S.A, U.K.
This is sensible when the abbreviation is in the middle of the sentence. For example: "The U.S. market is doing great."

However, this is an issues when the abbreviation appears at the end of the sentence. For example, NLTK do not split the following two sentences into two: "During 2003, we improved our focus on core customers in regions outside the U.S. As a result, several agreements were completed...".

I thought of using 'U.S.\s[A-Z]', but this would not work since there are instances where a capitalized letter appears after the abbreviation in the middle of a sentence. For example, "The U.S. Dollar...". Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no.

[Sentence segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation) has been an open problem for decades in NLP. The best systems get accuracy in the high 90s—but so does a simple rule-based baseline. There will always be exceptional cases that a model misses, no matter how natural they seem to you.